# MigLayout: Resize components relatively to a screen size

Tags: java, swing

I am using `MigLayout` to align components in the Swing application. I have 2 `JPanel` components and a toolbar. I want to put toolbar on top and then to put 3 panels next to each other, however their size should be defined in percentages (%) and be relative to a screen size.
I know how to align all these components based on fixed size (px), however how can I switch to % relative to screen size?

```
JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
contentPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 4, 4, 4));        
contentPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("fillx,insets 1")); 
JScrollPane westPanel = new JScrollPane(createParametersPanel());
JScrollPane eastPanel = new JScrollPane(createPanel());        
JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane("text/plain", "Hello World");
contentPanel.add(toolbar,"wrap");
contentPanel.add(westPanel,"width :200:");
contentPanel.add(editor,"width :200:");
contentPanel.add(eastPanel,"width :400:");
setContentPane(contentPanel);
```

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you want the size relative to the screen size and not relative to the contentPanel size?

Comment: @reowil: Probably it would be better to size the `contentPanel` relatively to the screen size, and then all the components should be sized relatively to the `contentPanel`. But I have doubts how to do this in a proper way.

Comment: So the actual goal becomes making the window occupy a certain percentage of the screen? (And then size the components relative to that size.)

Comment: Have a look at the description of "sp" in the whitepaper mentioned in one of the anwers (http://www.miglayout.com/whitepaper.html): "sp - Percentage of the screen". Perhaps that will do what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to use directly % width inside `MigLayout` try this example :

```
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);

        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
        contentPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("insets 4 4 4 4",
                "[fill,30%][fill,40%][fill,30%]", "[fill,grow]"));

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Open");
        menu.add(item);
        menubar.add(menu);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);

        contentPanel.add(new JScrollPane());
        contentPanel.add(new JScrollPane(new JEditorPane("text/plain", "Hello World")));
        contentPanel.add(new JScrollPane());
        frame.setContentPane(contentPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

To fully undestand how to use `MigLayout` follow this [Whitepaper](http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/mavensite/docs/whitepaper.html).

Comment: Thank you. Instead of `frame.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);` I need to adjust the size of JFrame to a screen size. Do you know how can I do this?

Comment: @KlausosKlausos Try to use `JFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)` for maximized frame.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos If you want full screen mode try this [Full Screen Mode](http://pastebin.com/raw/Biigej2N)